# Is there some equivalent function in python for pack from php?

Tags: php, python

I'm not familiar with binary operations in general, so for PHP i did it by examples, but can't find anything for python... I need something in python like in php `pack('H*'` and `pack('a*'`.

Comment: And what does `pack()` do?

Comment: @sshashank124 http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php

Comment: Note: Googling "python pack" gives me the `struct` module documentation as first result...

Answer (score 1):

The python [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html%29) module is what you're looking for.

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack("<H", 5) # Little endian short, 2 bytes.
'\x05\x00'
```

Do note that [`php.pack()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) `H` is not the same as struct `H`.

If you want to convert an integer to a hexadecimal:

```
>>> import random
>>> hex(random.randint(0, 100))
'0x4c'
```

but in python hexadecimals are strings, so I'm not sure if that's what you're asking. If you want to actually *pack* the output of `random.randint()` as binary data, pack the value as some integer. You can use the format characters `B, H, I, L, Q` at least.

Comment: `<H` equivalent to `H*` and same for a ?

Comment: may be you can show for example how to do this  `pack('H*', mt_rand())` ?

Comment: What is the output of that command? What exactly are you trying to do in python, because if you want to generate hexadecimals, then just call `hex()`.

Comment: don't know hot to show exactly, but here it is ` php -r "echo pack('H*', mt_rand());"
X�V�`

Comment: By the way, from phpdoc H - Hex string, high nibble first

Comment: What do you actually want to do? If you just want to print things, use `hex()` or pythons string formatting to produce the hexadecimal representation.